# Datatable que conserva la información

Tags: vb.net, .net, datatable

esperando que se encuentren todos bien quisiera consultar lo siguiente. ¿Alguien conoce o sabe si existe alguna manera de declarar un DataTable en VB.Net "global"?.
Con "global" me refiero a si es que yo cargo el DataTable desde una base de datos después de presionar un botón, cuando en el desarrollo realice otra acción (generar un excel con ese DataTable por ejemplo) los registros que cargué en el DataTable no se pierdan y asi no tenga que volver a cargar el DataTable otra vez con la misma información.
Quedo atento a sus comentarios y muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: No veo porque deberias perder tu datatable.. aunque ya es algo viejo usar un datatable ;)

Comment: Debes formular mejor la pregunta, porque si tienes conexión a una db, y estas cargando los los registros con datatable, no se pierde la info

Comment: Se me pierde la info ya que el DataTable no le cargo la informacion directamente desde la base de datos. Lo que hago es armar dos DataSet con los registros que necesito ya que el DataTable se arma desde dos bases de datos distintas, luego recorro los registros de los DataSet validandolos si son los registros que necesito mostrar y luego los inserto en el DataTable, cuando el DataTable esta ya armado lo inserto en el gridview...